# How to iterate over an vector and then compare it with a cin?

Tags: c++

I want to iterate over an vector and then compare each iteration with an cin.
But I dont have any clue how to do this.
`

Heres my try:

```
cout << "Willkommen bei der Anmeldung!\n\n";

            string username;
            cout << "Gebe deinen Benutzernamen an: ";
            cin >> username;
            for (int user = 0; user < users.size(); user++) {
                if (!username._Equal(users[user])) {
                    cout << "Dieser Benutzer existiert nicht!\n";
                }
                else {
                    cout << "Du bist eingeloggt!";
                    string login;
                    cin >> login;
```

Comment: Why not use `std::find`?

Comment: im new to cpp, didnt knew this function exists. I try it. Thanks!

Comment: Always use `std::getline` for User names.  The `operator>>` will not read a full name that has spaces in it.

Comment: Don't forget [range `for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) exists, so you can `for (auto&& user : users)` and forget about this index stuff. It's messy and often pointless.

Comment: Since when does [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) have a `_Equal()` method?  How does it differ from `operator==()`?

Comment: As far as I know it's completely the same

Comment: @FlorianDohms If something like `_Equal()` even exists, it's an implementation detail. Do not use it, since most likely [other compilers won't compile it](https://godbolt.org/z/PvjnY33PK). Simply use `if (username != users[user])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
auto it = std::find(users.begin(), users.end(), username);

if (it != users.end()) {
  // User exists
}
else {
  // User does not exist
}
```

Comment: I figured it already with a similar way. Thanks!

Comment: Ah right, I was thinking of `std::find_if`. You're right that `std::find` is much easier as you can just pass the value without a lambda.

Comment: With C++23, [`std::ranges::contains(users, username)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/contains)